# Considering the Black and Scholes model, check that $\ln(S_T)=2W_T$ in a particular case

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

I have the following problem with its solution, but I keep on getting it wrong. I would be really grateful if someone could please explain to me what I am doing wrong. Thanks! **It is part C that I don't understand**, but I have included parts A and B to give you an idea of what the problem is about. Thanks a lot in advance!

**QUESTION:** Let us consider the Black and Scholes model of a financial market where investors can trade in a risky and in a riskless asset. The risky asset follows the dynamics

$$dS_T=\mu S_t dt+\sigma S_t dW_t, t\in\mathbb{R}, S_0=s>0,$$
$\mu, \sigma$ are positive constants while the price of the riskless asset is described by
$$dB_t=rB_t dt, B_0=1,$$

where $r\ge 0$ denotes the risk-free rate. Here $W_t, t\in\mathbb{R_+}$ is a Brownian motion. We denote by $F_t, t\in\mathbb{R_+}$ its natural filtration. The trading period is assumed to be the interval $[0,T]$.

**PART A** Write down the Radon-Nikodym density $dP^*/dP$ of the unique $P^*~P$ such that the discounted price $\tilde{S}_t:=S_t/B_t$ is a $P^*$-martingale, $t\in[0,T]$.

**Part A - Answer**
$$\frac{dP^*}{dP}=\exp\{-\frac{\mu-r}{\sigma}W_T-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\mu-r}{\sigma}\right)^2T\}$$
**Part B** Write down a formula for $S_T$ using the $P^*$-Brownian motion
$$W_t^*=W_t+\frac{\mu-r}{\sigma}t,\quad t\in[0,T].$$
**Part B - Answer**
$$S_T=s\exp\{\left(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)T+\sigma W_T^*\}$$
**PART C** Consider an option with payoff $G=2W_T$ at time $T$. Choose $r=0$, $T=1$, $s=1$, $\mu=2$, $\sigma=2$. Check that in this case $G=\ln(S_T)$.

**Part C - Answer**
$$\ln(S_1)=\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\right)+2W_1=2W_1$$
**MY ATTEMPT**
We have
$$G=\ln(S_1)=\ln\{\exp\{\left(0-\frac{2^2}{2}\right)+2W_1\}\}=-2+2W_1$$

**What have I done wrong? It is almost the same as the actual answer, but that $-2$ is not supposed to be there.**

Comment: "What have I done wrong?" You are given $\mu=2$, but you use $\mu=0$.

Comment: Oh thanks, it seems so obvious now... I got the answer.